# Connection closed error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am getting connection closed error on my web API post method when the debugger hits the below BOLD line. Everything else seems to be working. I even increased time and length in the web configuration.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;  
var uri = new Uri("https://localhost:19810/api/.../insert/");
string message = string.Empty;
if (client != null)
{
    try
    {

        **var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, lookup);**

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            message = "Record inserted Successfully";
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
    {
        // because timeouts are still possible
        message = oce.InnerException.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        // Because other things can still go wrong too (HTTP 500, parsing errors)
        message = exc.InnerException.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Karl did you answer to my post?

Comment: I figured out the issue. I tried inserting a record which violated the primary key constraint. Thanks.